# Test for variation using random effects model

Tags: r, random-effects-model

I am think that it is possible to analyse **a model with just random effects** but I am not sure as I have never done it. I am looking for guidance on whether it is appropriate, what assumptions I need to be aware of, and how to do it properly.

From my study of an insect;

- I have a response variable (age at death, "age")
- Two treatments
  ("Treat1" and "Treat2") both of which have two levels (Treat1 has
  "A" and "B", and Treat2 has "P" and "Q")
- There is also 40 genotypes
  (1-40)
- With four replicates (w,x,y,z) of each combination of
  Genotype/Treat1/Treat2
- Each replicate contains 50 individuals

Put simply, my data looks like 32000 rows of this:

```
Treat1  Treat2  Genotype  Block  Individual   Age   
A       P       1         w      1            23
A       P       1         w      2            35
A       P       1         w      3            44
.       .       .         .      .            .
.       .       .         .      .            .
.       .       .         .      .            .
B       Q       40        z      50           76
```

I would like to know if each combination of Treat1 and Treat2 (AP,AQ,BP,BQ) have genetic genetic variation - i.e. is there variation between my 40 genotypes within each treatment combination?

I think I need a model for each of AP, AQ, BP, and BQ, along the lines of

```
Age ~ Genotype [ Treat1 == "A" & Treat2 == "P"] * Block [ Treat1 == "A" & Treat2 == "P"]
```

Where  Genotype and Block are random effects. I hear Gamma distribtions are better to use in lifespan (time to death) models.

**My questions are:**

a. Is this an appropriate way to show whether or not my genotypes have variation?

b. Can I build the four models as defined above or is that a really poor way of doing it?

c. If possible, what functions should I be using in R (lm, glm, lmer... & summary, summary.lm, aov, anova...)?

d. What should I expect, if gamma is more suitable than gaussian, to see when I compare `plot(model)` for gamma compared to gaussian?

---

This is currently my model...

```
AP= df$Treat1=="A" & df$Treat2=="P"
apmodel<- lmer(df$Age[AP]~(1|df$Genotype[AP])+(1|df$Block[AP]))
summary(apmodel)
```

Which I think is right but I'm not sure what to do with the output..

```
> summary(apmodel)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: df$Age[AP] ~ (1 | df$Genotype[AP]) + (1 | df$Block[AP]) 
       AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
     57343 57371 -28667    57336   57335
    Random effects:
     Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     df$Genotype[AP]  (Intercept) 17.23798 4.15186 
     df$Block[AP]     (Intercept)  0.15416 0.39263 
     Residual                     93.18777 9.65338 
    Number of obs: 7757, groups: df$line[AP], 40; df$Block[AP], 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  49.9948     0.6939   72.05
```

**Is there genetic variance??**

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could do to test whether there is genetic variance.

First, however, I wonder why you want separate models for "each combination of Treat1 and Treat2 (AP,AQ,BP,BQ)"? I don't know anything about the substantive area of application here, and I may be misunderstanding your data, but I think you can have 5 varying intercepts / random effects here: Block, Genotype, Treat1, Treat2, and Treat1.Treat2 -- an interaction term that you create and add to the dataset. One model for everything.

Anyway, back to your question.

First, a formal test of significance can be conducted by running this model using ML (using REML = FALSE):

```
apmodel1 <- lmer(Age ~ (1|Genotype) + (1|Block), df, REML = FALSE)
```

Then running a model without the Genotype effect:

```
apmodel2 <- lmer(Age ~ (1|Block), df, REML = FALSE)
```

And performing a likelihood ratio test:

```
anova(apmodel2, apmodel)
```

Second, and more informally, you might calculate statistics such as the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) to provide a measure of how much variance Genotype is accounting for. Try the `ICC.lme` function from the `psychometric` library.

Finally, the most interesting method would be to produce plots of predicted effects, with their corresponding uncertainty estimates for each Genotype, Treatment, etc. The focus here shifts from Genotype as a factor, to each level of Genotype as a (modelled / varying) effect.